# ZeroMq PUSH/PULL ensure that PUSH queue is empty

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

I have a architecture with 2 modules (one in C++ and one in Python) that communicates via ZeroMQ with PUSH/PULL sockets.The PUSHER is the C++ module and the PULLER is the Python module. A third module communicate in REQ/REP with these 2 modules to request for specific command (e.g start, stop, kill, ...).

My Python module cand be started in 3 different modes and can switch between them when requested via REQ/REP. When switching between modes, both C++ en python modules are stopped (going into IDLE STATE) and then started again. the C++ has only one mode but it goes into IDLE_STATE because orthewise it works for nothing and continue filling its sending queue for nothing.

But the problem is that the python module first receives stop request and then the C++ module. So, C++ module has time to continue filling its queue before stopping. Thus, when starting again in another mode, the python module will first get messages from the previous mode before getting messages from the actual mode.

So, is there a way to avoid this behavior? I was thinking of making a "clearQueue" function in python module so that it receives the remaining messages (and throw them to trash) before starting the C++ module.

Answer (score 0):

I did more research to try to find a solution, but it seems that there is no simple solution to it. The Hight Water mark (i.e the qeue size) can be set to a specific value, so I was thinking of setting it to one, but it can still end up with one message remaining in the queue. No one to help ?

EDIT: I actually added the following on the python side, wich i found quit awfull. But cannot get another solution.

```
try:
    while True:
        self.bus.receiveData(zmq.NOBLOCK)
except:
    pass
```